# Create images from same Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a nodejs application, which has two entry points **worker.js** and **web.js**

Basically, **web** should respond to all incoming http requests and **worker** should do some backend tasks.

Here is the question, how can I create two separate images from the same codebase? The problem is I can't create separate folder inside of my project with different Dockerfiles because I can't execute `ADD ../ /app` and I don't want to keep two copies of codebase. Project is in git repo but not published.

`bash
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name app-web application-web
docker run -d --name app-worker application-worker`

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly what you want to achieve, maybe create an image with the common part of the Dockerfile, call it mybase, then in the first Dockerfile `FROM mybase ADD ../ /app` in the second Dockerfile `FROM mybase other stuff`

Comment: Well, then I have to create common image and two other images, which now I have to have three Dockerfiles instead of two, which is quite confusing. Sorry if my question now very clear.

Comment: yes, but the build time will be nearly instantaneous, as you will do very little when you build application-web or application-worker

Comment: What about having one image, since codebase is the same? Just use it  with different parameters when you run it by setting different environment variables and properly handling them in the app configuration code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with one image per code-base, and use `--workdir` or just different `CMD`s to start the appropriate script:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name app-web -w /app/web application
docker run -d --name app-worker -w /app/worker application
```

Comment: I thought about that but didn't knew whether it's good idea or not.

Answer (score 1):

Abdullah's answer is the recommended one IMO (to save some disk space).

But to answer the default question, you can build an image with 2 different tags:

```
# assuming we're in the Dockerfile directory
docker build -t application-web .
docker build -t application-worker .
```

Then run different containers from these images:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name app-web application-web
docker run -d --name app-worker application-worker
```